# REST calls to a self-signed,not certified website using Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, ssl

I'm trying to post some data to a website using APEX, by executing a PL/SQL code.

The problem is, the website's certificate is self-signed, so it's not properly certified, and I'm getting the below error:

> ORA-29273: HTTP request failed ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_HTTP", line 1130
>   ORA-28860: Fatal SSL error

I'm using the below code:

> procedure publish_error_tickets
>
> is
>
> ```
>  req utl_http.req;
>  res utl_http.resp;
>  url varchar2(4000) := 'https://some_url';
>  name varchar2(4000);
>  buffer varchar2(4000); 
>  content varchar2(4000) := 
>  '{
>  "issue": {
>    "project_id": 1,
>    "subject": "Example",
>    "priority_id": 4
>    }
>  }';    begin
>
>  req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
>  utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
>  utl_http.set_header(req, 'content-type', 'application/json'); 
>  utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));
>
>  utl_http.write_text(req, content);
>  res := utl_http.get_response(req);
>  begin
>    loop
>      utl_http.read_line(res, buffer);
>      dbms_output.put_line(buffer);
>    end loop;
>
>    utl_http.end_response(res);
>  exception
>    when utl_http.end_of_body 
>    then
>      utl_http.end_response(res);
>  end;    end;
> ```

My question is, is it possible to somehow ignore the certificate validation process for the http message? There must be a way to reach a website without the need to buy a validated cert for the site.

Thanks in advance, 
Tamas

Comment: To connect to anything with utl_htttp via SSL you must add the certificate to your Oracle wallet and call utl_http.set_wallet.

Comment: Yes, I already know that, but the thing is the server runs on Oracle XE, so we don't have access to oracle wallets, that's why I'm asking if it's possible to just bypass the whole ssl handshake thing like in java.
Although there is a workaround for Oracle XE, but if it can be done without wallets we would like to try that out first.

Comment: Yes, there is. I use XE as well, and use an Apache reverse proxy so that Oracle can connect by http. For more info refer: http://blog.rhjmartens.nl/2015/07/making-https-webservice-requests-from.html

Comment: Awesome, got it working, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone having the same problem, I got it working with the solution Jeffrey Kemp posted( http://blog.rhjmartens.nl/2015/07/making-https-webservice-requests-from.html ), with a reverse proxy, it works like a charm!